# What is this mesh cover on the wall?

Tags: walls, speakers

I just noticed this thingy on the wall of my apartment. Weird I haven't paid any attention to it since I bought this place. I could swear I just heard a low-pitched sound coming out of it. Is it a speaker? If so, where could the sound have come from?

[image]

Comment: Are you in a large apartment building that might have modern fire alarms?  Larger buildings should have some way of alarming from a central alarm (as opposed to the little standalone models), and it's possible that is part of that system.

Comment: i hate hearing the listeners too; ruins the illusion of privacy.  just kidding. it could be alarm, doorbell, or just covering up a cheap contractor's "oops" in the drywall.

Comment: @Joe Yup, I am in a tower with 30+ stories. A central alarm makes sense. That must be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a large apartment building, it may be a fire alarm or a speaker for the doorbell system (functional or no longer functional if they've switched to a cell phone based system).  Those are very common in larger buildings that are required to have a central alarm instead of only unit-by-unit alarms.